# Controls not working

Tags: c#, controls

I have added my main class, from which I call buttons class, and that's where it's supposed to print out the button. The code is compiling ok, but I can't see the actual button. Seems to me it didnt inherit the controls properties. Thank you!

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Windows;

  //main class
  namespace Test
  {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     buttons button1;

     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        print_button();
    }

    private void print_button()
    {
        button1 = new buttons();
        button1.print();
    }


   }//form
  }//test

//---------------------------------------------------------------//

//buttons class
namespace Test
{
  public class buttons : System.Windows.Forms.Control

  class buttons
  {
     private Button button1;

     public buttons()
     {

     }

      public void print()
      {
          button1 = new Button();
          button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44);
          button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54);
          button1.Text = "next";
          Controls.Add(button1);
     }
  }//class
}//test
```

Comment: Oh man... For `Controls` to exist, this method should be inside a **form** or `buttons` should inherit `Control`. I believe that you want the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I have added inheritance, but I still can't see the actual label on the form

Comment: Please, post some more information about your project. What type is it (Win forms, Web forms, ...) and you're trying to do.

Comment: I have added couple things, if you could take a look, thank you!

Comment: You don't need that `buttons` class. Move the `print()` method to the `Form1` class and call it whenever you want. Form's `Controls` collection is different from the `buttons`' `Controls`.

Comment: I do need a separate class, I've got too much things in main, thus I'm separating stuff. I know i can do that everything from main, which I've already done, but I need to know how use different classes

Comment: You are trying to refactor your class? I think you are going about it the wrong way but without a better explanation I can't offer much advice.  I have updated my post below though.

Comment: If your concern is simply not to have too much code in one source file, then look into using partial classes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) for a very simple technique that might prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with the code you have provided. In any event the reason this method doesn't work:

```
public void print()
{
   button1 = new Button();

    button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44);
    button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54);
    button1.Text = "next";
    Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

is because the class 'buttons' does not define a Controls collection nor does it inherit from a class that exposes a controls collection.  For example if you were to do this:

```
public class buttons : System.Windows.Form
{
    ...
}
```

Your code would then at least compile since the Form class exposes a Controls collection. It isn't entirely apparent what you are trying to accomplish though so this solution may not suit your needs.  Post more information as appropriate and I will do what I can to help you.

-----Edit

It seems like you are trying to refactor your Form1 class from one of your comments above.

You could do something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void foo()
    {
       Controls.Add(buttons.print());
    }
}
```

and modify your buttons class as:

```
public class buttons
{
   public static Button print()
   {
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44);
     btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54);
     btn.Text = "next";
     return btn;
   }
}
```

This will then add a button to your main form's control collection once it is called.  As wrote though this method is useless since it can only produce the same button over and over.  I would modify the method so that it looks like this

```
   public static Button print(Point buttonLocation, Size buttonSize, string buttonText)
   {
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Location = buttonLocation;
     btn.Size = buttonSize;
     btn.Text = buttonText;
     return btn;
   }
```

And then the main form looks like this:

```
    public void foo()
    {
       Controls.Add(buttons.print(new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44), new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54), "button text"));
    }
```

Does this help?

--- Edit 2 ---

I am supplying this edit as a strictly academic example of how you could keep your main class (Form) 'cleaner' per the OP's request in the comments.  I don't suggest using this method in production and would instead recommend using a pattern such as MVC, MVP, or MVVP.  I am excluding examples of those patterns here because I think they exceed the skill level of the OP at this point in time and would only lead to more confusion.

Consider the following:

```
 public class buttons
 {
      private Form _form = null;
      public buttons(Form form)
      {
         _form = form;
      }

      public void print(Point buttonLocation, Size buttonSize, string buttonText)
      {
         Button btn = new Button();
         btn.Location = buttonLocation;
         btn.Size = buttonSize;
         btn.Text = buttonText;
         _form.Controls.Add(btn);
      }     
 }

 public class Form1 : Form
 {
     private buttons _buttons = null;
     public Form1()
     {
       _buttons = new buttons(this);
     }

     public void foo()
     {
        buttons.print(new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44), new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54), "button text");
     }
 }
```

Now here is what is happening: when Form1 is instantiated it creates a new instance of the buttons class and passes a reference of itself into the buttons constructor (_buttons = new buttons(this)) internally the buttons class sets this reference to the local variable _form so, therefore, anything  you do to the variable _form well be like if you were doing it directly to Form1.  As you can see that is what happens in the print() method where a button is created and then added to the Controls collection of _form which is the same as calling Controls.Add from within Form1.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I have added some info.I will appreciate if you could take a look

Comment: As @Andre Calil pointed out in a comment directly to your post, as written, there is no need for the separate class or the print() method.  If what you have is literally what you are trying to achieve simply move the print method to the Form1 class.

Comment: Is it very good explanation! Thanks. However, I'm still wondering if there is easier way to solve this problem. Cant I just add my button to controls inside the buttons class, somehow? This makes much more sense to me, and it keeps my main class cleaner. But thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Please take a look at 'Edit 2' above for some additional information.

Comment: Thanks a lot @abszero. This makes much sense

Answer (score 1):

Your class `buttons` isn't a subclass of `System.Windows.Forms.Control` so it has no `this.Controls` member.

I suggest use use the WinForms Designer in VS instead of creating your own forms or controls by hand, at least while you're a beginner.

I also note that you should conform to .NET style conventions. Classes and public members should use TitleCase and should exist within a namespace. Change `buttons` to `Buttons` (if you want to use that name) and wrap it in a `namespace` block.